# Exception caught by widgets library RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..35: 36

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-http

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'Products',
         ),
       ),
    body: Center(
       child: FutureBuilder(
          future: fetchPhotos(),
               builder: (ctx, snapShot) {
                    if (snapShot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                         return CircularProgressIndicator();
                     } else {
                    return ListView.builder(
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                         return ListTile(
                          leading: CircleAvatar(
                             backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                          ),
                           title: Text(snapShot.data["table"][index]["name"]),
                           subtitle: Text(
                              "price: ${snapShot.data["table"][index]["class_id"]}"),
                       );
                     },
                   );
                 }
               },
              ),
            ),
          );
         }
```

What should I put in it itemCount so as not to show an error : Exception caught by widgets library RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..35: 36

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `itemCount` parameter to yout listView Builder as :

```
ListView.builder(
 itemCount: snapShot.data["table"].length,
 itemBuilder: (context, index) {
       ...
```

This way flutter knows when to stop building items

Comment: Displays only the first 3 items

Comment: It seems like you are displaying the tables object so it would be `itemCount: snapShot.data["table"].lenght`

Comment: Error : Exception caught by widgets library / Class 'List<dynamic>' has no instance getter 'lenght'.
Receiver: Instance(length:36) of '_GrowableList'
Tried calling: lenght

Comment: It was `length` not `lenght`,  sorry I misspelled it.

Comment: BTW @Jahidul you copy pasted it wrong too.